# Does DolphinDB have an equivalent method to Python join?

Tags: python, join, dolphindb

In Python, I can join all elements into a string separated by a string separator with method `join()`.

```
>>> ','.join(["{}D".format(i) for i in range(1,6)])

'1D,2D,3D,4D,5D'
```

How can I implement the function equivalent to join in DolphinDB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try function `concat` to form a string. The equivalent function can be implemented with the following script:

```
concat(string(1..5) + "D", ',')
```

The output is

```
1D,2D,3D,4D,5D
```